# Node.js Failing to Create App After updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint

I'm using Window's bash to create a react app ad I get this error. I tried updating eslint and using npx create-react-app xyz, however, I get the below error message.

```
$ npx create-react-app demo-counter
npx: installed 1 in 14.364s
Path must be a string. Received undefined
C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Rob\webprojects\september\demo-counter.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\Rob\webprojects\september\demo-counter has failed.
```

Comment: Which version of node are you running? (Use `node -v` in the terminal to check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be on an unsupported version of node. What's the output when you type `node -v` in your terminal?

Comment: $ node -v
v8.9.4

Comment: @RobB. try updating your version of node to `^8.10.0` since that's what the error message seems to be asking for